# How to invoke the eclipse search dialog programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am working on an eclipse RCP project which has added its own search dialog.

I would like to be able to find that dialog, pre-fill some of the fields (depending on selected items etc) and then open the dialog for the user to be able change settings before submitting the search.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which Search dialog - the 'Search > Search...' dialog with multiple tabs (which tab)? or the 'Find/Replace' dialog?

Comment: It would be the Search... dialog and I would want to pre-select and fill the search tab which my app provides

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```java
NewSearchUI.openSearchDialog(window, "page id");
```

to open the search dialog with the given page active. `window` is the active `IWorkbenchWindow`.

I don't see any standard way to initialize the page fields.

`NewSearchUI` is in package `org.eclipse.search.ui` in the `org.eclipse.search` plugin.